# wso2esb to connect servicenow to create tickets using wso2esb management console

Tags: servicenow, wso2-esb

I am trying to integrate servicenow with wso2esb management console. So please guide me how to develop this in console. As of now I have created a proxyservice data is in json format that is stored in log mediator(data is {"company":"ABC", "impact":"3","category":"Request","description":"Testing"}) and send mediator specified the servicenow url ( https://{instance}/api/now/import/incident) to create incident.

And when I executed it gave " INFO - HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://localhost:8280/services/Demo12.Demo12HttpSoap12Endpoint]
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"

Demo12 is the proxy service name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Authentication details in header mediator of the servicenow instance.
like this 

before sending to an servicenow instance endpoint.